# ¿Cómo crear tags anidados con prefijos en java?

Tags: java, xml

¡Buen día!

¿Cómo puedo crear la siguiente estructura en java?

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:exam="http://examtraPS/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <exam:Progra>
            <exam:PrograReq>
                <exam:ID>ID0900000000489500000000000001</exam:ID>
                <exam:ORIGEN>1</exam:ORIGEN>
                <exam:VIA>0</exam:VIA>
            </exam:PrograReq>
        </exam:Progra>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Actualmente lo quiero hace de la siguiente manera:

```
public static String esquema = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\""+"xmlns:exam=\""+"http://examtraPS/";
                String wsdl = propertiesManager.getProperty("url.properties", "example.url");
                MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
                SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
                SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
                SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
                SOAPFactory soapFactory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
                SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();

                Name name = envelope.createName("metodo", "", esquema);
                SOAPBodyElement soapMethod = body.addBodyElement(name);
                soapMethod.addChildElement(soapFactory.createElement("Progra", "exam:", esquema));
                soapMethod.addChildElement(soapFactory.createElement("PrograReq", "exam:", esquema));
                soapMethod.addChildElement(soapFactory.createElement("ID", "exam:", esquema).addTextNode(progra.getID().trim()));
                soapMethod.addChildElement(soapFactory.createElement("ORIGEN", "exam:", esquema).addTextNode(progra.getORIGEN().trim()));
                soapMethod.addChildElement(soapFactory.createElement("VIA", "exam:", esquema).addTextNode(progra.getVIA().trim()));
```

Pero los tags Progra y PrograReq están a la misma altura que ID, lo cual no es correcto, por que estos deberían estar dos niveles arriba anidando a ID, etc.

Gracias.

¡Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para crear un WS en eclipse tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

> //Para crear el web service: Creo un dinamic web proyect->programo una
>   clase con los metodos del web service
>
> //Clic derecho a la clase ->WebService->CreateWebService
>
> //La barra de arriba esta en "start service" y la de abajo en "no
>   client" que es configuracion por default
>
> //A veces sale un mensaje que pide algo de habilitar la escritura del
>   wsdl, darle si a todo
>
> //Tambien nos pide agregar un Server como tomcat Agregarlo
>
> //A veces sale una ventana con checks de UDDI Registry dar en finish
>   sin palomear nada
>
> //Mi wsdl queda en WebContent/wsdl
>   //http://localhost:8080/Miproyecto/services/MiClase?wsdl

Si creas el WS de esta manera todos los tags `soapenv` no los tienes que poner ni preocuparte por ellos ya que esto lo hace el lenguaje por ti y no solo en java, también lo hace C#, php, etc.

Pasando al segundo punto: `xmlns` significa xml namespace y quiere decir que lo que pongas después es una declaración de un espacio de nombres. Para crear un espacio de nombres tienes que crear un archivo dtd o un XSD que valide el contenido del XML en ese espacio de nombres. Este archivo debe de estar en un servidor de aplicaciones en algún lugar donde todo el mundo tenga acceso. Si lo va a utilizar un tercero debe ser publico en internet y si lo va a usar internamente una empresa puede funcionar si es publico en su intranet.
Todo esto es para que el XML que use ese dtd o XSD pueda acceder a el y poder hacer las validaciones correspondientes.

Puedes revisar este [tutorial de XSD](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/schemaxml/) para que sepas como crear uno. Si el XML a realizar es complejo puedes apoyarte en herramientas para XML como [XMLSpy](https://www.altova.com/xmlspy-xml-editor).

Para finalizar, si quieres crear un XML con código java, te recomiendo revisar la biblioteca [Xstream](http://x-stream.github.io/alias-tutorial.html), la biblioteca [StAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/using.html), [agregando atributos y namespaces con StAX](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/xml/stax.html#1105299) y revisar [mi respuesta en este post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/107174/pasar-de-xml-o-xsd-a-clase-java/107176#107176).

Comment: Gracias, justo lo que necesitaba.