# parse string xml

Tags: java

tengo el siguiente codigo XML en un string lo que quiero hacer es un  parse para poder imprimir la informacion pero no he podido con los siguientes .jar xerces, jdom y jaxp alguien sabe de otro ? o que versiones de estos podrían funcionar todos me lanzan error.

```html
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding= "UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE list 
><list>
  <ListaMaterias>
    <codigoMateria>3525</codigoMateria>
    <descMateria>Aprender Biologia</descMateria>
    <id>1</id>
    <nombreMateria>Biologia</nombreMateria>
  </ListaMaterias>
  <ListaMaterias>
    <codigoMateria>3678</codigoMateria>
    <descMateria>Aprender Quimica</descMateria>
    <id>2</id>
    <nombreMateria>Quimica</nombreMateria>
  </ListaMaterias>
</list>
```

Estoy intentando con JDOM  pero cuando deseo imprimir me imprime en blanco. osea no imprime nada solo 3 espacios en blanco.

```js
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    List resultado = null;
    resultado = new ArrayList<>();
    resultado = listarDatos();
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    String xml = xstream.toXML(resultado);

    String adicionar = "<?xml version = \"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\"?> \n";
    String doctype = "<!DOCTYPE list \n>";
    String xml_m = adicionar + doctype + xml.replace("<newwebservicematerias.Materia>", "<ListaMaterias>").replace("</newwebservicematerias.Materia>", "</ListaMaterias>");
    //System.out.println(xml_m);

    org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
    try {
        org.jdom.Document doc = saxBuilder.build(new StringReader(xml_m));
        String message = doc.getRootElement().getText();
        System.out.println(message);
    } catch (JDOMException e) {
// handle JDOMException
    } catch (IOException e) {
// handle IOException
    }

}
```

e intentado con

```js
        org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
        try {
            org.jdom.Document doc = saxBuilder.build(new StringReader(xml_m));
            List cadena = doc.getContent();
            for (Object iterator : cadena) {
                System.out.println(iterator);
            }

        } catch (JDOMException e) {
// handle JDOMException
        } catch (IOException e) {
// handle IOException
        }
```

pero lo único que e imprime es:

```
[DocType: <!DOCTYPE list>]
[Element: <list/>]
```

Comment: Agrega lo que has intentado y te marca error, es importante para que los desarrolladores te ayuden, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Según la documentación de JDOM v1.1.3:

> **getRootElement()**
>             -This will return the root Element for this Document

Deberías usar el getContent(), que según la documentación devuelve un `List` con el contenido del documento.

```
 try {
    org.jdom.Document doc = saxBuilder.build(new StringReader(xml_m));
    resultado = doc.getContent();
    for(List iterator: resultado){
       System.out.println(iterator);
    }
} catch (JDOMException e) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que ya te revolviste: o usas sax o usas xstream. Xstream es mas potente pero no es magia y te faltan muchas clases de configuración. Te invito a que revises [mi respuesta en este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/107174/pasar-de-xml-o-xsd-a-clase-java/107176#107176). Por ejemplo te faltan las clases java que representan el xml,te faltan los `converter` como en mi ejemplo `StringConverter` y te falta el driver de configuración como en mi ejemplo `XstreamTransformacion`:

```
package ejemplo.xstream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.SingleValueConverter;
public class StringConverter implements SingleValueConverter {
    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class arg0) {
        return arg0.equals(String.class);
    }
    @Override
    public Object fromString(String arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(Object arg0) {
        return (String) arg0;
    }

}
package ejemplo.xstream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver;
public class XstreamTransformacion {
    private static XStream configuracion(){
        XStream xstream=new XStream(new DomDriver());
        xstream.alias("biblioteca", Biblioteca.class);
        xstream.alias("libro", Libro.class);
        xstream.addImplicitCollection(Biblioteca.class, "libros");
        xstream.useAttributeFor(Libro.class, "tipo");
        xstream.registerConverter(new StringConverter());   
        return xstream;
    }
    public static String toXML(Biblioteca biblioteca){
        XStream xstream=XstreamTransformacion.configuracion();
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"+xstream.toXML(biblioteca);
    }             
    public static Biblioteca fromXML(String xml){
        XStream xstream=XstreamTransformacion.configuracion();
        return (Biblioteca)xstream.fromXML(xml);
    }
}
```

Otra cosa que creo que te esta causando grandes problemas es tu XML. `<!DOCTYPE list>` Se usa en para definiciones en DTDs o XSDs pero tu estas en XML, por lo que aquí no va y creo que eso te esta metiendo mucho ruido.